# Excel DNA - Marshal C# string to VBA ByRef in callback

Tags: c#, vba, com, excel-dna

I am attempting to invoke a VBA callback in Excel from C# code using Excel-DNA. After messing around with the particular data types and marshalling declarations, I was able to finally create a working sample:

**C# Code**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[ProgId("CSharpComObject")]
public partial class CSharpComObject
{
    Dictionary<string, Callback> _callbackMap = new Dictionary<string, Callback>();


    public void SubscribeStringData(string topic, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] Callback callback)
    {
        _callbackMap[topic] = callback;
    }

    public void RaiseCallback(string topic, string data)
    {
        _callbackMap[topic](data);
    }

    public delegate void Callback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string data);
}
```

**VBA Module**

```
Option Explicit

Dim testObj As Object



Sub Subscribe()

Set testObj = CreateObject("CSharpComObject")

testObj.SubscribeStringData "someTopic", AddressOf StringDataCallback

End Sub



Sub StringDataCallback(ByVal data As String)

MsgBox "StringDataCallback Raised [" + data + "]"

End Sub
```

---

**Question**

As you can see from the code sample above, the default COM marshalling for strings is `BStr` a.k.a. `ByVal ... As String`.

I was wondering if there is a way to pass string data (or any object type for that matter) to the VBA callback `ByRef`, and if so, what would the C# declarations and marshalling attributes need to be?

Comment: Have you tried `ref string`?

Comment: If you can take an early-binding approach, an event would be more straightforward (though that would not address your question).

Comment: @Govert, I can't believe it (after trying a bunch of goofy manual `Marshal` calls) but simply putting the `ref` keyword on the C# side does it. Write up a formal answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the parameter as `ref string` should work.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx for more information about the string marshaling options.

Comment: ... should and does work. The Interop marshaler can be surprisingly intelligent sometimes. Note this is the equivalent of manually calling `Marshal.StringToBSTR(..)` and passing the `IntPtr` by `ref`. Either way, performance-wise, passing the string `ByVal` or `ByRef` is almost identical, since the BSTR conversion always creates a copy.